# Is it possible to set different -Property value for ReferenceObject and DifferenceObject to compare in Compare-Object?

Tags: powershell

Consider comparing objects in `$refs` and `$difs`:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ref -DifferenceObject $dif -Property $property
```

What about if I want to compare `$refs[i].Name + ' new'` with `$difs[i].Name`? What kind of `$property` should I set?

Comment: [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.2) as documented, for those switches, only accept: ```Compare-Object ---        [-ReferenceObject] <PSObject[]> ---   [-DifferenceObject] <PSObject[]>```. Just capture what you want as an object to a new variable and pass that in.

Comment: @postanote Yeah, the script block works.

Comment: @postanote To clarify, what I've done is in -Property value because I need to get the original objects when comparing calculated properties.

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `$ref |Join $dif -on { $_.Name + ' new' } -eq Name`